# Moderators' communications leaked!

Tags: cipher

An [online community](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) has three moderators: [Doorknob](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/39/doorknob), [Kevin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4/kevin), and [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20/emrakul) (in no particular order). In between making posts on [meta](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com), they decide to set up a code for their private communications, and start sending secret messages to one another. First Doorknob sends Emrakul this message:

$2211+1211=111+21+11+2111+1+1112+221+121=1221+2111+2122+2111+1=1112+1121=1211+121+2122+2122+2111+1222$

Then Emrakul sends this one to Kevin:

$1211+121+1121+221+121+1+2212+21+1211=1112=1121+21+1222=21=2212+2111+2=21+12+2212=21=1221+21+221$

Finally Kevin sends this to Doorknob, closing the circle:

$1112=2122+1112+2112+121=21+2121+2121+2122+121+1121=21+12+2212=2111+1+21+12+2+121+1121$

Can you decrypt the messages?

Comment: I'll have to refrain from answering, since they posted the key to their code in Teacher's Lounge a few weeks ago. *le sigh*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

Quite simply:

> The ones and twos correspond to Morse code dots and dashes. The plus signs are letter separators, and the equals signs are word breaks.

That gives you

> 1. ZL SNIBEVGR PBYBE VF LRYYBJ
>  2. LRFGREQNL V FNJ N QBT NAQ N PNG
>  3. V YVXR NCCYRF NAQ BENATRF

Then all you need to do is

> A 13-place Caesar shift (rot13)

To obtain:

> 1. MY FAVORITE COLOR IS YELLOW
>  2. YESTERDAY I SAW A DOG AND A CAT
>  3. I LIKE APPLES AND ORANGES

Comment: Well done! This was much easier than I expected :-(

Comment: Note to self: change codes.

Comment: @Emrakul - You think that'll work? I'm the Julian Assange of Stack Exchange! :->

Comment: This is exactly how the mods talk, too.

Comment: @Emrakul Change them so that all communiques are valid mathematical expressions as well as encoded.